# Azure Publishing

Tags: publishing

I have recently begun using Azure for hosting our site. I have the publish from Visual Studio 2010 setup and working. However, it seems to take down the instances and reinitialize. The problem is that it takes up to 20 minutes to publish even the smallest of changes and the server settings are reverted.

Maybe I am misunderstanding how to do this efficiently. What I want is a way to publish just application updates via VS2010.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're stuck with the 20 mins. Make sure your install package contains every setting you need. You cannot rely on changes made on the server, because if there is something wrong with the running instance, then it will also be recycled. You'll lose your settings then too.

Comment: Thanks you are correct. After talking to MS support the thing I was missing is the staging instances. They recommend you publish to staging, then swap VIP's. This they happens instantly. They also said creating service packages and upgrading through the management portal will allow you to not recreate the instance.